# When should the Ajax code be loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I am using Ajax on my website to submit forms without reloading the current page. I put the code with all my Javascript: right before the `</body>` tag.

However I noticed that when I load a page and submit a form before the end of loading, the page reloads like the Ajax was not there.

This is how my code is now:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="ajaxForm"></form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#ajaxForm").on("submit", function(e){
                $.ajax({});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think that the code below could do what I do, but **I would like to use the selector** (eg. `#ajaxForm`) as a trigger element to execute the Ajax.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitForm(){
                $.ajax({});
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="ajaxForm" onsubmit="submitForm()"></form>            
    </body>
</html>
```

How should I arrange my code to use Ajax properly, even when the page loading is not completed yet?

Comment: The first one is good (just before the `</body>` tag), and you shouldn't have any issues if the form comes before the script. You can try wrapping the whole thing in the document ready function `$(function(){ /* code here */});`. Edit: You could try setting onsubmit to return false for the form to prevent the default submission...

Comment: How does the user submit the form before the page is finished loading?

Comment: When the form submit button is loaded, I can click on it and therefore the form will be submitted if no action is taken to prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what Mark suggested:

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="ajaxForm" onsubmit="return false;"></form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#ajaxForm").on("submit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The " onsubmit="return false;" " will prevent from classic submitting at anytime. And this is what I needed.
" e.preventDefault(); " alone is not sufficient, especially when it is loaded at the end of the body.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to prevent the default action of the form submitting.

You can achieve this by adding `e.preventDefault();` into your first script:

```
$("#ajaxForm").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({});
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when this script is put at the end of the body, it is also loaded after the HTML. What happens when the page is loading (and when the upper part of the HTML is loaded, but not the lower part which includes the script) and I click of the submit form button, the form will still be submitted normally. onsubmit="return false;" will prevent from submitting instantly when the HTML of the form is loaded.